# allow azure asp.net website to serve x3d files

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config

I want to serve x3d files by my azure asp.net website. I tried in web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions applyToWebDAV="false">
          <add fileExtension=".x3d" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".bin" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the web.config and add those file extensions as mime types.

Please see the following artcile: http://blogs.iis.net/richma/adding-mime-types-to-your-windows-azure-web-site

The following example is for .woff font files:

Add the following to the    section of your web.Config.

```
<staticContent> 
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" /> 
</staticContent>
```

Note : If the  element already exists you just need to add the  element  to this section for the type you want to add